# How to store a List of IGrouping<int, object> to single List<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm grouping a collection of list from the 364 days of data per month then loop using foreach. 
Then I used the GroupBy to group them by month. 
After grouping they're are group for 12 months with 30 days of list in single month. 
But my problem is how to store the 12 months in a single List?

```
var inventories = new List<Month>
{
    new Month { Id = 0, Name = "JAN", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 1, Name = "FEB", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 2, Name = "MAR", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 3, Name = "APR", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 4, Name = "MAY", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 5, Name = "JUN", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 6, Name = "JUL", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 7, Name = "AUG", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 8, Name = "SEP", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 9, Name = "OCT", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 10, Name = "NOV", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" } } },
    new Month { Id = 12, Name = "DEC", Inventories = new List<Inventory> { new Inventory { Id = 1, Name = "Can", Description = "Can Description" }} },
};

var list = new List<Collection<Month>>();

// Currently I have 12 months that has a Inventories per month.
foreach (var month in inventories) 
{
    // Just store the 12 months in a single List<T>
    // Example: [0] -> [12] - > [30] and so on.
}



class Month
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Inventory> Inventories { get; set; }
}

class Inventory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Question is not clear. You wrote "how to store the 12 months in a single List?" and "I expect output should have a 3 or more List".   Which is it?

Comment: I expect output should have a 3 or more List.

Comment: Currently, I have 12 list which is the months with 30 days of List inside a single month. Then I just need them to store in a List<T>. Expected output is [0] -> [12] -> [30], [1] -> [12] -> [30], [2] -> [12] -> [30], so on.

Comment: I still do not understand how you get that output from a list. It's a hierarchical output so there is obviously more going on that outputting a flat list or even a series of lists. What are you trying to accomplish overall?

Comment: @JohnWu I updated my sample code. Please, see it. Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you gave a test data and result set. From what I understand, you do not want to aggregate at a month level, but at a cumulative level where one list will have from month 1 to 12, second list will have month 2 to 12 and so on till the last list which will have only for the 12th month (12 to 12)

Comment: What is the data type of the final result? Do you just want a single `List<Inventory>` containing the inventories of all the months combined? If so just use `inventories.SelectMany( m => m.Inventories ).ToList();`

Comment: No, I just need to store the 12 months to a single List<T>.

Comment: What T? `List<Inventory>` for example? Need to know exactly what structure are you trying to populate. You already have a single `List<Month>`.

Comment: any type of T. I just need the 12 items or months they're add on single collection. Example: [0] > [12] > [30],  [1] > [12] > [30], and so on...

Comment: What do you mean by `[12]`??? I suggest updating your question (again) to be clear, don't try to clarify in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear question but I think you can try this rather than use two models , you can achieve with hierarchical

```
    public class Inventory 
    {
        public Inventory()
        {
           MonthList = new List<Month>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Month> MonthList {get; set;} 
    }

    public class Month
    {
        public Month()
        {
           DayList = new List<Day>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Day> DayList {get; set;} 
    }

    List<Inventory> inventoryList = new List<Inventory>()
    {
       new Inventory()
       { 
           Id = 1,
           Name = "test", 
           Description = "desc.",
           MonthList = new List<Month>()
           {
              Id = 1, 
              Name = "test", 
              Description = "desc.",
              DayList = new List<Day>(){...}
           }
        }
     }
```

Iterating results

```
foreach(Inventory inv in inventoryList) //--> inv will be contains more than 3 list
{
   inv.MonthList.... //--> it will be contains 12 months
   foreach(Month month in inv.MonthList)
   {
      month.DayList... //--> will be contains 30 days
   }
}
```